# xcode: how to set correct setting for text searching?

Tags: xcode, search

I have install xcode 6.4 . After installation xcode searching not working in Editing area (coding area) properly. For example : when I search let  "delegate" word in a class or entire project and suppose that class/project contains total 10 "delegate" words. Then it show first time search result correct for 10 "delegate", but when "delegate" words comes at lowest bottom or topmost, xcode does not search and show "delegate" word again. In my old version xcode it search top to bottom or bottom to top automatically when searching finished. Please help, how to do this in this xcode . **Any suggestion will be great. Thanks in advance !!**

Comment: May anybody help me ?

Comment: I am not getting any help , Please help....

Comment: Finally I have solved my above issue in xcode in just 1 step. Just open terminal and write this : **defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode** and hit enter key, this is for xcode version 5 and later , for old version just hit this one : **defaults delete com.apple.Xcode** These are the officially recommended way to delta Xcode 5's preferences.

Comment: I found what was the exact problem. How to solve : **Go to edit find options and click on it>check mark on Wrap** Done , see difference when you search text in class/console with check wrap and uncheck wrap option.